# why dosent this python JSON script not work

Tags: python, json

i have made this script for a simple chatbot but i am having trouble with fixing the constant errors inside of the script this is the python file

```
import json
import random

# Load the JSON data from the specified file path
file_path = "chatbot_responces.json"
with open(file_path) as file:
    chat_data = json.load(file)

def chat(category, step_data):
    while True:
        print(random.choice(step_data['responses']))
        user_input = input("> ").lower()

        found_match = False
        for words in step_data['words']:
            if words in user_input:
                found_match = True
                break

        if found_match:
            if 'answer_from_user' in step_data:
                next_category = step_data['answer_from_user']
                next_step_data = chat_data.get(next_category)
                chat(next_category, next_step_data)
            else:
                break
        else:
            print("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again.")

def restart_chat():
    print("Listening for conversation starters...")
    while True:
        user_input = input("> ").lower()
        for category, step_data in chat_data.items():
            found_match = False
            for words in step_data['words']:
                if words in user_input:
                    found_match = True
                    break
            if found_match:
                print(f"Starting conversation in category: {category}")
                chat(category, step_data)
                break
        else:
            print("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    restart_chat()
```

and this is the json data i am using

```
{
    "greetings": {
        "words": ["hello", "hi"],
        "responses": ["Hi", "Hello"]
    },
    "continuation": {
        "words": ["who are you", "what is your name"], 
        "responses": ["idk", "you tell me"]
    }
}
```

the result is

```
Listening for conversation starters...
> hello
Starting conversation in category: greetings
Hi
> what is your name 
I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again.
Hi
```

it is soppost to output one of the randomly generated responces in the json for example one of these options would have been picked

'idk'

or

'you tell me'

making a correct responce

```
Listening for conversation starters...
> hello
Starting conversation in category: greetings
Hi
> what is your name 
idk
>
```

Comment: There's a space at the end of your second question, so it will never match. `'what is your name ' != 'what is your name'`. Consider changing input line to not only lower(), but also .strip() to get rid of trailing whitespace

Comment: Where is `step_data['answer_from_user']` in the JSON?

Comment: it is used for embedded questions inside of the individual question dict inside the json file, this is to simulate contextual conversations